# How do I convert a diagonal line pattern in my *.psd to a Photoshop pattern?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, css, background, patterns

In my psd from designer I have a background like in the red rectangle.

[image]

This pattern doesn't show up in any Photoshop patterns. (maybe it's inner psd container)

How could I fetch a small rectangle from Photoshop and use it as a `css` background, having it repeat seamlessly without any bugs or borders etc.?

How do I fetch repeated content for a background from a `.psd` layout?

Comment: Hi @brabertaser1992, I tried to rewrite your question to clarify it and clean it up. If I mangled your original intent, don't hesitate to roll back my edit or re-edit it!

Answer (score 1):

Creating a seamlessly repeating pattern image involves making the image yourself, and ensuring it's seamless on all sides in a variety of ways. you can then select it and choose <kbd>Edit... > Define Pattern...</kbd>. That adds your chosen image as a pattern to Photoshop's available pattern options.

You can load or save new patterns using the `Layer Style` popup (<kbd>double click</kbd> the empty part of a layer in the layers palette or choose <kbd>Layer > Layer Style... > Pattern Overlay...</kbd>) by clicking on the small gearwheel icon when you choose a pattern.

Ensuring your pattern is seamless can be tricky. Sometimes a clever choice of your unit cell is all you need, but it can be much trickier than that. Especially turning a photo image into a seamless pattern will involve copying parts of your unit cell to the opposite end and applying a gradient mask to the copied part.

In `css`, you could use such a resulting image as a repeating background—no need to specify anything, `background-repeat` is set to `repeat-x` and `repeat-y` by default.

There are alternatives, like making your pattern in all `css` like with [Patternify](http://www.patternify.com/), a browser-based repeating pattern builder, or using and/or tweaking one of the patterns in the [CSS3 Patterns Gallery](http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/), among others.

Comment: i know about css and patterns. but how to select pattern from psd source, that would be resulting image without ofsets etc